# Google apps script: how to edit/modify an existing script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have created a Google apps script "to download attachments from GMail" from a tutorial. I executed that script for one time.

Then I logged out of Google. Now when I logged in again, I saw the desired script titled "gmailAttachment2drive" in my Google drive. But I want to edit it again to make some changes to it. But I am unable to do it. I cannot even see the source code of that script.

Here are the different things I tried and the responses I got:

- If I click on it, I see some "connect app" pop-up type of page, which just shows a bunch of other scripts developed by other people.
- If I right clicked it, I don't see any option to edit the script. I tried all options there but could not edit the script.
- When I opened "https://script.google.com/" it doesn't show that script. When I clicked "Open" on the File menu, it showed "No saved projects to open"

So, how do I open an existing script that is there in my Drive?

I searched a lot on Google the following "Google apps script how to edit an existing script" but could not get any help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you still have the url to run it?

Comment: @Sergeinsas No. But I can see some URL when I hover my mouse on the script name listed in my Drive. But when I right click I cannot copy that URL. But thanks, I could see the URL from the share option. I could start editing it only after I pasted the URL from the share option. But it is a cumbersome way to start editing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the "Create" button. (The button used to create new documents)
2. Located at the bottom of the menu you will see a "Connect more apps" link, click it.
3. Add the Google Apps Script editor to your Google Drive
4. Open the script